# How is "Stack Exchange" pronounced in practice in a non-bilingual environment?

Tags: pronunciación, nombres-propios, inglés

How is "Stack Exchange" pronounced in practice in a non-bilingual environment?

Reason I'm asking: in Mexico, at least, proper names starting with ST are uncomfortable for those not fluent in English (NFE), noting that the vast majority of the population is NFE.  If you're talking about, say, Oliver Stone, Stone will become "Estón."  And a fair number of people in Mexico, when talking about someone named Axel, will say "Atsel."  And "Stack Exchange" presents additional hurdles for a Spanish speaker to produce, even if he has a mental image of how someone fluent in English pronounces it.

Comment: Our Russian teacher was always complaining about us saying _espasiba_ instead of _spasiba_...

Comment: The link by @walen explains it all, about why we pronounce "estac ekschanch" or so

Comment: Let me make an analogy...Is it important to talk about the "spin" of the electron if you don't know what an electron is?. Is it important to know how "stack exchange" is pronounced in an environment where no one speaks English? Among that non-bilingual group it is obvious it will be pronounced as if it was Spanish and they will all happily agree.

Comment: Always. "estac eschéin", and endings can actually be "ein", "einj" or "ench"

Comment: @DGaleano and whoever upvoted your comment -- It's not *important*, but nevertheless interesting to me.  I haven't felt it is safe to travel to Mexico with my children for too long because of the levels of violence.  I use this site as a way to still feel connected. // Or are you saying that a NFE person will have no awareness of SE and therefore no need to talk about it and pronounce it?

Comment: @FGSUZ - Sounds like an answer!

Comment: @aparente001 No. What I'm saying is if there is a group that ONLY knows ONE language then any written thing they see will be automatically pronounced as if written in their language and they will all agree on that. (given that the set of characters is understandable to them) and then the answer to your question would be trivial for any language. Why would someone doubt the pronunciation of something if he only knows one way of pronouncing things.? If they have a minor knowledge of something else, then they will have doubts. (1/2)

Comment: @aparente001 (2/2) it is like the old saying ["A man with a watch knows what time it is. A man with two watches is never sure."](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segal%27s_law)  Given this then FGSUZ comment will be a very good educated guess (I'm not sure if and absolute answer because if you give that to a computer that only speaks Spanish it would say something like ecs-chan-je)

Comment: @FGSUZ why someone that only speaks Spanish would say "eschéin" to something written exchange? Form where will that person imply that "ange" sounds "ein" instead of "an-je" if his only knowledge is the Spanish pronunciation ? I'm sure finding a person that ONLY knows Spanish and had never heard some English is the difficult part here and so your answer makes a lot of sense.

Comment: @aparente001 and BTW I used the word "important" on my other comment and that was no exactly what I meant. I was just stating the analogy. If you asked then obviously the question is important to you. Sorry for that.

Comment: @DGaleano - Thank you very much for your last comment.

Comment: @DGaleano - Monlingual Spanish speakers are exposed to people who speak some to a lot of English (unless they live in an isolated environment in which case they would have no awareness of the existence of StackExchange).  This influences their interpretation of written English.

Comment: could this be a duplicate of how words in a different language are pronounced in Spanish ?

Comment: @Mike - Do you have a specific link I could look at?

Comment: @walen - I've reviewed what's on topic, what's off topic, and the other question asking guidance.  I can't find "not useful" as a reason to close.  There are plenty of questions on this site which I personally am not interested in, and which have no practical usefulness -- but I don't vote to close them only for that reason.  I figure, the person who asked finds it interesting, and maybe some others do too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From @DGaleano:

> "estac eschéin"

The ending could also be "einj" or "ench."

Answer (score 1):

Following the rule of "read as it is written" the pronunciation of a NSE is:

> Stack ecschan**j**e

"Stack" would sound quite similar due to the phonetic connection between "ck", and "S" having no "E" visually (or typed) attached. If someone pronounced it as "Estack," it would be because he/she has a notion of English pronunciation.

Comment: Do you mean *because he/she **does not have** a notion of English pronunciation*?

Comment: @aparente001There is a misconception of how to pronounce some words that start with "S" (es) words in English, for Spanish speakers. So I do mean "he/she has a notion of" leading to pronounce with an "E" before "S" : estack.

Comment: Thanks for responding, but I just don't understand what you're saying there.  It sounds like your sentence means, *only those who have some familiarity with English would have difficulty starting the word with the "ST" sound; and those with NO familiarity with English would not "cheat" and add a vowel sound (e) before the S.*